# Cannot open any uac required program sometimes

Tags: windows-7

My computer boot up slowly and have a strange behaviour:
SOMETIMES when I boot, from a RANDOM moment after going in to desktop, it will start to "block" all programs that requires administrator privilege from running(when attempted nothing happens), and it looks like the boot up process just stopped. sometimes if the moment happens pretty early, I get infinite desktop screen with only a cursor, sometimes it happens in the middle of opening all startup programs. Sometimes ALL programs will not run(when attempted nothing happens). Sometimes when I try to restart it stuck at logging off infinitely.
This kind of strange behaviours happens more and more frequently. I use to encounter it every 10-20 reboots, and then 3-4 reboots, now I have to reboot multiple times to see a boot without problem.

Some of my conditions:
I forgot to make a disk D so I filled 99 percent of my disk C. I think this is the reason why I have a slow boot up. 
I have attempted system scan, chkdsk, malware scan in safe mode, no problems at all.

System spec:
Windows 7 home premium 64-bit
Intel core i7 3770k
8gb ram

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Additionally, when i encounter the problem, if I use task manager to terminate explorer and open it again, when I attempt to run any folder or control panel it says "the remote procedure calls failed". Also during the problem in task manager If I hit the "show processes from all users" button which requires uac, the task manager will freeze.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, your HDD is too full and that will certainly slow down your computer. This will also cause everything to slow down.

The first thing I would do is get another HDD and off load at least 60% (more if possible) of what's on your "C" drive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will a full drive cause the described problem as well?

Comment: A full drive will give all kinds of problems. Never fill more than 80 - 85% of a drive, unless it is purely for backup/storage.

Comment: I'm not trained and cannot be sure, but it seems to me that that IS the problem. Your instrument cannot access all the info it needs quickly, so everything will lock until it has the info I need. There may be other problems, but there is no way to tell. Offload and see what happens. Here's more info. See #3. :http://ca.norton.com/yoursecurityresource/detail.jsp?aid=slowcomputer

Comment: Will shrinking C and make a D disk and offload data there help?

Comment: No. The total size of "C" now is the total physical area available on that HDD. Any partition will just take from this total size.

Comment: I have bought an external hard drive and managed to offload data, but I found that some programs and video games will not run if they are being put in drive other than C because of reason related to privilege I suppose. This should be in another thread but I hope this should be an easy issue to solve.

Comment: Get rid of this thread. Ask you new question by opening another thread. If you like my answer here, you can accept it and I will get a small reputation bonus.